# Python - standard deviation of chosen rows in each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I would like to calculate the standard deviation for each column in the data frame, but only for the selected rows. I would like to reflect this formula from Excel (calculates standard deviation only for highlighted cells and moves one index down each column)

[image: fromula in excel]

Could you please advise me how should I construct my loop to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to better explain your problem and post the code you have tried so far

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use numpy for that:

example input:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50).reshape(10,5,order='F')).add_prefix('m')
>>> df
   m0  m1  m2  m3  m4
0   0  10  20  30  40
1   1  11  21  31  41
2   2  12  22  32  42
3   3  13  23  33  43
4   4  14  24  34  44
5   5  15  25  35  45
6   6  16  26  36  46
7   7  17  27  37  47
8   8  18  28  38  48
9   9  19  29  39  49
```

output (here using 5 rows):

```
>>> pd.Series(np.c_[[np.diagonal(df.values, offset=-i) for i in range(5)]].std(axis=0), index=df.columns)
m0    1.414214
m1    1.414214
m2    1.414214
m3    1.414214
m4    1.414214
```

This works by creating an intermediary array:

```
>>> np.c_[[np.diagonal(df.values, offset=-i) for i in range(5)]]
array([[ 0, 11, 22, 33, 44],
       [ 1, 12, 23, 34, 45],
       [ 2, 13, 24, 35, 46],
       [ 3, 14, 25, 36, 47],
       [ 4, 15, 26, 37, 48]])
```

imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```